# what is the limit of $\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle{\sum _{t=1} ^n} a^{t/n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Could you please help me with the limit of the sum of the series $$\frac{1}{n}\sum _{t=1} ^n a^{t/n}$$ with $a$ a parameter between $0$ and $1$ ? I did not find anything on internet.

Thanks a lot by advance

Comment: it is basically going to be 0 since you divide the sum by n approaching infinity.

Comment: Apparently not or very slowly. I simulated the sum with excel until $n=10000$. The sum converges to a number between $a$ and $1$.

Comment: Have you learned about Riemann sums?

Comment: @AbuBakr that's incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

You can interpret the sum as a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), so in the limit you get the integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} a^x \,dx. $$

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the partial sums by interpreting the sum as the one of the terms of a geometric progression :

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n a^{\frac{t}{n}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n (a^\frac{1}{n})^t$$

Comment: I'm not sure : the coefficient a^{1/n} varies with $n$.

Comment: @A.Direr. This is very correct since $n$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As Santeri stated, we can interpret the sum as a Riemann sum, which comes down to converting any expression of the form:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1 n\sum_{k=0}^n f\bigg{(}\frac k n\bigg)$$

and, since $\frac 1 n$ determines a partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ parts, if we evaluate $f(x)$ at every point of the partition $(\frac 0 n, \frac 1 n, \frac 2 n, ...,\frac n n)$, we'll get an approximation, that tends towards the full area beneath the function $f(x)$ that is, of course:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx$$ And in your case $f(x) =a^x$.

Comment: I got it.Thanks to all for your help